# WMI calling method

Tags: c++, windows, wmi

I'm trying to change Intel network adapter settings using WMI. Accessing the classes works fine but according to the [Intel documentation](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/9405/eng/wmi_scripting_reference.pdf?) page 40 i need to call two methods in order to apply those changes.

So the IANet_NetService class should have the methods BeginApply and Apply. When I check this using PowerShell command `get-wmiobject -namespace root\intelncs2 -class IAnet_NetService | get-member` I can confirm that these methods are present.

The Intel documentation says I should enumerate the single instance in IANet_NetService.

So when I use `CreateInstanceEnum` method it will give me one result in the enumeration, but when I try to enumerate the methods for this instance, it won't find any.

Later I tried to use `CreateClassEnum` which had no results.

At last I tried a simple `GetObject` call to get the IANet_NetService item. With this item I was also able to enumerate the methods and find the BeginApply and Apply methods.

It is also possible to call `GetMethod` to receive the signature information. For the BeginApply method it has no input parameters which is correct according to the Intel docs. So I try to execute this method using `pService->ExecMethod(L"IAnet_NetService", L"BeginApply", 0, 0, 0, &pOutInst, 0);` which return `WBEM_E_INVALID_METHOD_PARAMETERS`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392103(v=vs.85).aspx) says this may be returned when the input parameters are wrong or I'm missing a [static] qualifier on the method.

The input parameters are correct, but I do not know what the missing [static] qualifier means in this case.

Anyone knows how to call this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that i needed to use the `GetObject/GetMethod` combination to retrieve the input parameters and after this get the only instance of the object and ask for it's path. This path replaced `L"IAnet_NetService"` on the `ExecMethod` call and it's working.

Comment: Would you demonstrate how do you get the "only instance of the object" and ask for it's path ?

I have the same issue.

Comment: Use `CreateInstanceEnum` on the namespace and the call the `Next ` function once on the returned enum.

Answer (score 0):

**WMI Method call without parameters:**

This one is the exact code reference:

```
    IEnumWbemClassObject * enum_obj;
    hres = pSvc>CreateInstanceEnum(_bstr_t(L"IANet_NetService"),WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY , NULL ,&enum_obj);


   IWbemClassObject * spInstance;
   ULONG uNumOfInstances = 0;
   hres = enum_obj->Next(10000, 1,&spInstance,&uNumOfInstances);

   VARIANT path;
   hres = spInstance->Get(_bstr_t("__Path"), 0,&path, 0, 0);

   IWbemClassObject *results = NULL;
   hres = pSvc->ExecMethod( path.bstrVal, _bstr_t( L"Apply" ), 0,
   NULL,NULL,&results, NULL );
```